# How to solve PyCharm unresolved reference for builtin functions like read.csv?

Tags: python-2.7, csv, ide, pycharm

> Using Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit) with PyCharm-4.5 IDE

having an annoying problem here. My code as follows,

```
cpdtr <- read.csv("../Data/train.csv")
```

For the above line of code the ide shows error as follows

```
Unresolved reference "read"
```

1. I did the File->Invalidate/restart. After the IDE start its seems ok, but after it finishes indexing, again the errors come.
2. I have already marked the project root as source directory and its blue coloured now.

Still the problem remains. Please throw some light.

Answer (score -2):

import csv file as follows

```
csv.reader("../Data/train.csv")
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.